# Django FileUploadHundler force file storage to Disk

Tags: django, file-upload

I understand that Django File Upload Handler by default stores files less than 2.5MB to memory and those above it to a temp folder in the disk,
In my models,where I have a file field,I have specified the `upload_to`folder where I expect the files to be written to.
Though when I try reading this files from this folder,I get an error implying that the files do not yet exist in that folder.
How will I force django to write the files to the folder specified in upload_to before another procedure starts reading from it?
I know I can read the files directly from memory by `request.FILES['file'].name` but I would rather force the files to be written from memory to folder before I read them.
Any Insights will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#file-upload-max-memory-size) setting tells django the maximum size of file to keep in memory. Set it to 0 and it will be always written to disk.